# Ajax encoding parameters before send?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, encodeuricomponent

I have this ajax call

```
$.cordys.ajax({
        url   : "xxx"
        method: "xxx",
        namespace: "xxx",
        parameters: {
            Lines : {
                "@xmlns" : "http://www.exemple.com",
                Line : TFLines
            }
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }

    }).fail(function(error) {
        alert(error);
    });
```

I would like to send an object Lines which is a collection of Line, the object TFLine is an array and looks like this:

```
[{
  @xmlns: "http://exemple.com",
  Code: "DENOLEGAL",
  Comments: "",
  Content: "<![CDATA[<strong>test</strong>]]>",
  DisplayedLanguageId: "1",
  DisplayedLanguageName: "FR",
  IsMandatory: "1",
  Label: "Dénomination légale de vente"
}, {...}
]
```

My problem is with the field Content where I have special characteres.
This data have to be sent in Json Format but in the target application it will be convert into XML (this is why i need to enclose my data with CDATA tag)

Juste before the ajax call my dataset looks exactly like this but when I look into the console the request payload, the field Content has been encoded like that:

```
&lt;![CDATA[&lt;strong&gt;test&lt;/strong&gt;]]&gt;
```

I thought the ajax library did that, actually not, i put breakpoint everywhere the library use encodeURIComponent(), anyone stopped

Do you have an idea why this happen ??

Answer (score 0):

The payload was HTML encoded (not URL encoded). So, you could find out if some part of the code is Html-encoding the payload data

The payload should be encoded as

```
%3C!%5BCDATA%5B%3Cstrong%5Btest%3C%2Fstrong%5B%5D%5D%5B
```